# Pandas transform list values and their column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with 1 row and values in columns by separated by categories

| car > audi > a4 | car > bmw > 3er | moto > bmw > gs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [item1, item2, item3] | [item1, item4, item5] | [item6] |

and I would like to create structure something like this:

| item | category 1 | category 2 | category 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item 1 | car | audi | a4 |
| item 1 | car | bmw | 3er |
| item 2 | car | audi | a4 |
| item 3 | car | audi | a4 |
| item 4 | car | bmw | 3er |
| item 5 | car | bmw | 3er |
| item 6 | moto | bmw | gs |

What is the best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
(df.set_axis(df.columns.str.split('\s*>\s*', expand=True), axis=1)
   .loc[0].explode()
   .reset_index(name='item')
   .rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('level_', 'category'))
)
```

Output:

```
  category0 category1 category2   item
0       car      audi        a4  item1
1       car      audi        a4  item2
2       car      audi        a4  item3
3       car       bmw       3er  item1
4       car       bmw       3er  item4
5       car       bmw       3er  item5
6      moto       bmw        gs  item6
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'car > audi > a4': [['item1', 'item2', 'item3']],
                   'car > bmw > 3er': [['item1', 'item4', 'item5']],
                   'moto > bmw > gs': [['item6']]})
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), where for this particular use case, you pass a separator to `names_sep` to split the columns and pass a list of new column labels to `names_to`, before `exploding` the `values_to` column:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df
.pivot_longer(
    index = None, 
    names_to = ('category1','category2','category3'), 
    names_sep = ' > ', 
    values_to = 'item')
.explode('item')
.sort_values('item') # not necessary
)

  category1 category2 category3   item
0       car      audi        a4  item1
1       car       bmw       3er  item1
0       car      audi        a4  item2
0       car      audi        a4  item3
1       car       bmw       3er  item4
1       car       bmw       3er  item5
2      moto       bmw        gs  item6
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `explode` function that is a pandas built-in.

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)